# Ubuntu PHP returning invalid MSSQL Server date format

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, laravel-5, freetds

My PHP/Laravel App is hosted on ubuntu 14, php 5.5.
The app is connecting to Sql Server via freetds/odbc.

In my freetds.conf
I have these settings for date time:

```
[default]

date format = %Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S.%z
```

In my database Datetime is stored as:

```
2016-12-07 07:11:31.000
```

When I run query against my db I get this date:

```
Dec  7 2016 07:11:31:000AM
```

I tried all possible solutions. Can anyone please help me sort out this issue?
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The FreeTDS FAQ suggests that the `date format` directive belongs in [locales.conf](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/locales.htm), not freetds.conf.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an invalid date format . You can format it according to your need by using this example :

```
<?php
$date =date('m-d-y', strtotime('Dec  7 2016 07:11:31:000AM'));
echo $date;
?>
```

Comment: No I want the system return in the default format in the sql server.